# Cloud Functions for Firebase timing - How long do google functions idle?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

What is the idle time between the last function execution and Cloud Functions for Firebase needing to initiate a "cold" start? Can this "idle" time be adjusted?

In production this isn't an issue, but dev testing.